# GWT 2.8.1 opera support

Tags: java, gwt, opera, smartgwt

We have a running application written on GWT 2.4 with opera (Opera 11.64 Build 1403 for Linux i386) integrated. Now we are thinking to upgrade our application to use GWT 2.8.1.

But it doesn't seem to work with the opera version I have mentioned. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: You are aware the current version of Opera for Linux is 45 ????
Using Opera 11 today does not seem like a smart idea to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera 11 uses Presto layout engine ([doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29#Web_browsers)).

GWT FAQ page, updated 31 jul 2016 says (page [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#Browsers_and_Servers)):

> What browsers does GWT support?
>
> GWT supports the following browsers:
>
> ```
> Firefox
> Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10, 11
> Safari 5, 6
> Chromium and Google Chrome
> Opera latest version
> ```

That said the answer is: maybe, if you are lucky.

I strongly suggest you to use a newer browser, you will have better performances and a more secure environment.

Also if you want to update consider that GWT 2.8.2 will be available soon with Java 9 support.

Comment: I'm interested about "GWT 2.8.2 will be available soon with Java 9 support". Do you have any source for this?